# Making an expensive call to an API and updating a loading bar on the UI with the current status of the call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am making a call to an API that could take a while to process. I want to show the user a loading bar on the UI.

I put some thought into how I would go about doing this, but I am not sure if it is the correct approach.

1. User makes expensive call to the API.
2. API returns an OK that it started processing. Maybe it will also return a threadId or something.
3. I would then make subsequent calls using that threadId to figure out where it is at in the process to update the loading bar.

I am using an ASP.NET Webforms application that use HttpClient in the code-behind to make calls to an ASP.NET Core Web API. I am not making these calls directly through JavaScript.

If I were to use SignalR would I be adding SignalR to my webforms application or to the WebAPI?

Comment: What you have described is "polling". That is probably the way to go unless you can use web sockets .

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you for giving me the term of what I am looking for. Now I can do better research.